# Generated code in csproj not picked up correctly by build

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, csproj

I have an SDK-style csproj file and I would like to generate some code with NSwag before the build starts.

For this I created a custom target

```
<Target Name="NSwag" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Command="$(NSwagExe_Net70) openapi2csclient ..." />
</Target>
```

While this target successfully generates me a client class from the provided swagger definition file, the build only runs successfully after the first build.
On the first build it generates the code and the build fails because the code using the generated code cannot find it.
The errors say `The type or namespace 'Foo' does not exist in namespace 'Namespace.Of.Generated.Code'`

If I start a second build it builds successfully.

What I would like to achieve is that the code is generated before compiling the code and not having to at least run the build two times for it to complete. I tried several different targets in the "BeforeTargets" attribute like "Compile", "Build", "CoreCompile" but some of them either didn't work at all (probably because they didn't exist) or didn't change the behaviour I get with `BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"`.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the classes are generated but not picked up by the build.
Try adding the generated files to the MSBuild `Compile` item so that the build knows to compile them.
This works for me in both VS and the CLI:

```
<Target Name="NSwag" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Command="$(NSwagExe_Net70) openapi2csclient ..." />
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="MyAutoGeneratedRelativeFolder/**/*.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Just replace `MyAutoGeneratedRelativeFolder` with the output folder of your code generation.